# How Does Node.js + Express Find Pre-Rendered Views?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

I would like to pre-render my Jade files with a Gulp task, so that my views are not rendered on-the-fly. From my understanding, if one is using the Jade view engine with Express 4, this is how the Jade templates become their HTML equivalents (please correct me if I am wrong).

I realize that the views directory is typically pointed to using the statement `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/directory');`, where `app` is an Express app. However, I am not sure how to force Express to serve the pre-rendered HTML files instead.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think using Express' [sendfile](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendfile) method should work.

Comment: Seems plausible. Have you used the method for this purpose?

Comment: Nope, never tried it since I only use live-rendered views generated by a template engine. But I don't see why that wouldn't work. Have you tried ? Please note that you should apparently use `sendFile` instead of `sendfile`. `sendfile` seems to be deprecated since v4.8 of Express

Comment: I plan on trying tonight -- I'll post results